Запустить при выполнении инсталлятора exe файл с параметрами
Есть приложение exeшник, который выполняется через powerShell с параметрами:
abc.exe archive "C:\asa\app.asar" address add -u "http://abc:8092"
Хочу сделать, чтобы это выполнялось автоматически из инсталлятора, после нажатия на кнопку next в диалоге. Диалог выглядит так:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <Property Id="MYTEXT" Value="http://localhost:7701" />
        <UI>
            <Dialog Id="ConfigurePoolDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="!(loc.SelectPoolIdentityDlgHeader)">
                <Control Id="TitleImage" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="44" Text="WixUI_Bmp_Banner" />
                <Control Id="Title" Type="Text" X="15" Y="6" Width="210" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.SelectPoolIdentityDlgTitle)" />
                <Control Id="Description" Type="Text" X="25" Y="23" Width="280" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.SelectPoolIdentityDlgDescription)" />
                <Control Id="BannerLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="44" Width="370" Height="2" />
                <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="Вперед">
                    <Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
                </Control>
                <Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Cancel="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUICancel)">
                    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CancelDlg">1</Publish>
                </Control>
                <Control Id="Back" Type="PushButton" X="180" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Text="!(loc.WixUIBack)">
                    <Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="CustomizeDlg">1</Publish>
                </Control>
                <Control Id="BottomLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="234" Width="370" Height="2" />
                
                <Control Id="UserNameLabel" Type="Text" Height="17" Width="75" X="30" Y="83" Text="!(loc.LoginLabel)" />
                <Control Id="SpecificUserName" Type="Edit" Height="17" Width="200" X="115" Y="83" Property="MYTEXT"  />

            </Dialog>

            <Dialog Id="SelectPoolIdentityValidationDlg" Width="250" Height="100" Title="!(loc.SelectPoolIdentityValidationDlgHeader)">
                <Control Id="SelectPoolIdentityUserEmptyText" Type="Text" Height="30" Width="150" X="50" Y="24"
                         Text="!(loc.SelectPoolIdentityUserEmptyText)" >
                </Control>
                <Control Id="OkBtn" Type="PushButton" Height="17" Width="56" X="80" Y="68" Text="Ok">
                    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return">1</Publish>
                </Control>
            </Dialog>
        </UI>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>

Как это сделать и в файле диалога это надо делать или в product.wxs?
